# Reactjs & Paddle checkout

Tags: reactjs, paddle

I'm using https://paddle.com/ as as payment processor for my software.

I'm getting the error

> Page Not Found
> Sorry, the page you were looking for could not be found.` coming from Paddle and I wonder why, I have done everything correctly like on the docs.

My index.html

```js
    <script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/paddle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      Paddle.Setup({ vendor: xxxxx});
    </script>
```

main.js

```js
payment = () => {
      const Paddle = window.Paddle;
      const openCheckout = () => { 
          Paddle.Checkout.open({ product: xxxxxx});
      }

return(
     <Button variant="primary" onClick={openCheckout}>Subscribe Now!</Button>
)
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm currently having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the environment fixed the issue for me when testing against Paddle sandbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      Paddle.Setup({ vendor: xxxxx});
      Paddle.Environment.set('sandbox'); // <<<-------
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and here is what happened -

1. You need to have your domain approved in paddle checkout settings. (I had it)
2. You should not use www. before your site url while submitting your website in checkout settings (I did that and suffered.)

I was disappointed that even though my domain is approved, i am getting page not found while checkout. Finally I submitted the same domain without www and it started to work!

Paddle authority should really take a look at this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Live Paddle account checkout (not Sandbox, which always worked fine). For me, it was resolved after my identity verification was completed. You need a few things in place for your Live Paddle account checkout to work:

1. Domain verified (note that subdomains need separate verification)
2. Identity & business verification (you will be prompted to fill in some forms, take pictures of your id and record yourself on video - plus I think Paddle do their own checks - you'll be notified when this is complete)
3. Payout information submitted
4. Ensure you are using the correct Vendor ID and Auth Code (these are different for your live account than for the sandbox account)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I was able to resolve this by following :-

1. Domain you are using should be approved in paddle checkout settings.(Avoid www from domain while submitting for approval)
2. Product ID should be correct for that product as defined inside Catalog -> Products tab in paddle dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

You are probably using an incorrect product ID. You can find the product ID by getting a checkout link for the product in the catalog section of the Paddle dashboard.